# e.stopPropagation required to prevent click events from bubbling up to parent

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have a Marionette ItemView which is listening for a click on an `li`; all click events for ItemViews in the ui below that are being ignored for the click handler on the parent `li`.

I have found a workaround that involves calling `e.stopPropagation` but it seems the actual solution may be to target the anchor tag rather than the li.

Some sample code:

```
var LiView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    events : {
        'click' : function(e){
            console.log(e.target);
        }
    }
});

var AnchorView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    events : {
        'click' : function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(e.target);
        }
    }
});

new LiView({el: 'li'});
new AnchorView({el: 'li a'});
```

Without `stopPropagation` the li click event still fires - just as it would when you have multiple jQuery click handlers. The problem is that e.target will refer to the anchor in both the click handlers - something that is undesirable.

Any thoughts on a better way to structure this?

Answer (score 1):

I would just use `e.stopPropagation` since this is how event bubbling is supposed to work and you're wanting to prevent it from bubbling up.

Since you're binding to `click` in your `LiView` there isn't a way to get around that being called unless you bind to something specific in the `li` that is not the `a` or parent of the `a` (as bubbling would still be a problem here).

The alternative (which is messy in my opinion) is to check inside of the `LiView` click handler against `e.target` and `e.currentTarget` to make sure they are the same (if the `li` itself is what you want clicked unless other elements bubbling up is desirable):

```
events: {
  'click' : function(e) {
    if(e.target == e.currentTarget) {
      // the person actually clicked on the LI and not something inside of it.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: At one point I was comparing e.currentTarget - I believe this to be messy as well. Currently I have refactored to select a specific anchor in the `li` as the trigger to expend/collapse the accordion - but I have a suspicion that there is a better means of handling altogether. Great suggestions/explanation though, thanks.